# Align 2 divs while using draggable & resizable JQuery UI

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm working on a fun little project to learn JQuery, JQuery UI and JavaScript, but I've actually gotten stuck at a CSS/HTML related issue, but I think it has something to do with JQuery UI aswell.

I want to align the following 2 boxes next to eachother, so horizontal, but I can't use a flexbox as that would ruin the resizable function, and `display: inline-block;` just dosnt seem to work.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I did achieve this by using a flexbox, but as said it messed up the resizable function and made it funky when changing the width of the div/textarea.

This is the HTML for both divs.

```
<div class='drag resizable'>
<textarea class='resizable' type='text'></textarea>
    <div class='buttonDiv'>
        <i class='fa fa-paint-brush fa-lg color' aria-hidden='true'></i>
        <br>
        <i class='fa fa-trash fa-lg delete' aria-hidden='true'></i>
    </div>
</div>


.buttonDiv {
    background-color: #d9e4e8;
    height: 5.5em;
    border-top-right-radius: 10%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10%;
    display: inline-block;

}

.delete, .color{
    margin: 15px 8px 10px 8px;
    color: #364e59;
}
.drag {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:transparent;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow: visible;

}

.drag textarea {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
}

.drag textarea:focus {
    box-shadow: -5px 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.drag textarea:active {
    box-shadow: -5px 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/wzryne8o/

**A Lovely lad on a stream helped me out, here is the JSFiddle that fixed the issue.**

https://jsfiddle.net/v66ad8e3/3/

Comment: Provide some code

Comment: add snippet of the code

Comment: Btw try to remove any newline between the two div in the html source code.

Comment: Code snippet has been added @NadirLaskar there is no newline between the 2 divs.

Comment: Add full snippet please.

Comment: With what? It's the full snippet, the only other part is CSS and as I wrote, there is nothing that changes how its sorted. @NadirLaskar

Comment: @NiceDevelopmentq Its helpful to solve if you provide a working fiddle.

Comment: @NadirLaskar added CSS.